# Best JSF framework/library for "conversation state"

Tags: jsf

What do people think is the best JSF framework or library for a saving state longer than request scope (but w/o using session scope) that is backbutton/new window safe -- i.e. you have a "wizard"/multi-page form.

For example, [MyFaces has the 'SaveState' tag](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_saveState.html) that allows you to maintain state across pages by saving state in the view's component tree. Any comments on SaveState (pros/cons) or suggestions for any better framework or library for this capability?

Answer (score 1):

The `t:saveState` works perfectly. It's only a bit 'low level' and not tied to a particular bean. There are two other libraries/frameworks which comes to mind which provides control over conversation scope at higher level (e.g. bean-specific tags/annotations):

- [Apache MyFaces Orchestra](http://myfaces.apache.org/orchestra/index.html) ([uses tags](http://myfaces.apache.org/orchestra/myfaces-orchestra-core/usage.html))
- [JBoss Seam](http://seamframework.org/) ([uses annotations](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.1.2/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html#d0e1932))

**Update**: JSF2.0 has added a new scope which achieves a conversation-like state, the `@ViewScope`. Very useful if you can reuse the same view for subsequent actions.

Answer (score 0):

i think Spring Web Flow is a good solution. you can define your flow as XML and it can integrate with JSF, Struts, Spring MVC, ZK,...

http://www.springsource.org/webflow